# How to add custom document marshalling strategy to jbpm?

Tags: customization, marshalling, jbpm, business-process-management

Im using red hat bpm which is built on jbpm and I want to store uploaded attachments to the cloud storage. The problem is that I couldn't find any relevant documentation for doing this. I've read that I need to implement org.kie.api.marshalling.ObjectMarshallingStrategy but besides that I couldn't get any information about deploying my custom solution to the kie server.

I've created java class file which implements ObjectMarshallingStrategy and left all methods blank, just for deployment purposes.
But kie server threw this exception when I tried to deploy custom document marshalling jar:
"Error creating container 'com.example.test:test-document-marshalling:1.0-SNAPSHOT' for module 'com.example.test:test-document-marshalling:1.0-SNAPSHOT': java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find KieModule: com.example.test:test-document-marshalling:1.0-SNAPSHOT"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.